# alternative commandline tool to svcutil

Tags: wcf, command-line, wsdl, svcutil.exe

We are using the svcutil.exe to generate from WSDL. For some of our WSDL documents that contains import tags to other wsdl documents, we are having problems generating code. I spent a lot of time with this problem, but I don't find any solution for this problem.

```
<import namespace="http://example.com/stockquote/definitions"
       location="http://example.com/stockquote/stockquote.wsdl"/>
```

Generating code from WSDL that contains import tag is giving error:

```
Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding Detail: Cannot find definition for htt p://example.com/stockquote/definitions:StockQuotePortType. Service Description with namespace htt p://example.com/stockquote/definitions is missing. Parameter name: name XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/stockquote/service']/wsdl:binding[@name='StockQuoteSoapBinding']
```

This example is directly taken from the  [W3.org site import example](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_style)

When using the "Add service reference" in Visual Studio everything is going flawless. I'm giving up searching why it does not want to work with the svcutil.exe 
I do not want to spent any more time searching for a solution, but only for a alternative tool.

Are there any alternatives tools to svcutil ? We need a commandline tool that can generate code from WSDL

Comment: Are you saying that the target wsdl, itself, references wsdl files external web services? Or are you literally trying to reference a URI at "example.com", which is intended for illustration only? Sorry to seem dense, but I'm just not yet entirely clear on the problem.

Comment: the target wsld references an other wsdl in the same directory. It is not a URI as described in the example above.

Comment: I may be completely misunderstanding the problem here, and if that's the case, I apologize in advance, but I'm not clear why the consuming client needs to know about the WSDL used to define a *dependent* service. That is, Client A consumes WebService X, but WebService X consumes WebService Y. It sounds to me like you're saying that Client A needs to know about WebService Y. Am I understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: I hope that this comment will give more insight: WebService X imports WebService Y because WebService Y has common messages definied that is shared between other WebServices. WebService Y has also a link to corresponding scheme WebService.Xsd where common ComplexTypes are definied.